# Remove firt x characters and few last characters, too

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Could someone please assist me, since that could not manage to find exact solution. Namely, I have expression which is:

```
Actual Standings ( `1. Nov 2017 - 1. Dec 2017`)
```

Literally it looks like as typed above
I need to print out just following:

```
1. Nov 2017 - 1. Dec 2017
```

So, how can I remove first 7 characters (am I correct that there are 7 characters before **1. Nov** text) and also remove **`)** at the end of that string?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because it is a zero-effort requirements dump.  If you can [edit] your question to show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, or to clarify *precisely* where you are having difficulty, this downvote may be retracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this by getting first and last indices of (`):

Assuming your string is in `s`.

```
s = "Actual Standings ( `1. Nov 2017 - 1. Dec 2017`)";
System.out.println(s.substring(s.indexOf('`')+1, s.lastIndexOf('`')));
```

**Output:**

```
1. Nov 2017 - 1. Dec 2017
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Kaushal28